# Media recorder can not stream at the first time ask permision

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, audio-streaming, mediarecorder

When the first time get permission, event `ondataavailable` not working on chrome android, ios and safari, working perfectly on desktop. But after refresh, it works.

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
    });

mediaRecorder.value.ondataavailable = (event: BlobEvent) => {
   console.log('streaming')
}
```

how can i fix this, thanks